# Doing reduceByKey on each partition of RDD separately without aggregating results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD partitioned on the cluster and I want to do `reduceByKey` on each partition separately. I don't want result of reduceByKey on partitions to be merged together. I want to prevent Spark to do shuffle intermediate results of reduceByKey in the cluster.

The below code does not work but I want sth like this:

```
myPairedRDD.mapPartitions({iter => iter.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)})
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something

```scala
myPairedRDD.mapPartitions(iter => 
  iter.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ + _)).iterator
)
```

or to keep things more memory efficient (here I assume that `myPairedRDD` is `RDD[(String, Double)]`. Please adjust types to match your use case):

```scala
myPairedRDD.mapPartitions(iter => 
  iter.foldLeft(mutable.Map[String, Double]().withDefaultValue(0.0)){ 
    case  (acc, (k, v)) => {acc(k) += v; acc}
  }.iterator
)
```

but please note, that unlike shuffling operations, it cannot offload data from memory.